# multiple lines in animated python line plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, data-visualization

So I am trying to animate both the GDP Per Capita and Life expectancy with animated lines in the same graph.
My code is

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import matplotlib.animation as animation

data= pd.read_csv("data.csv")
print (data.head())
data_2007=data[data.year==2007]
print (data_2007.head())
china=data[data.country=="China"]


x_data=[]
y_data=[]
y1_data=[]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(1950,2010)
line, = ax.plot(0,0)

def animation_frame(i):
    x_data.append(china.year.iloc[i])
    y_data.append(china.lifeExpectancy.iloc[i])
    y1_data.append(china.gdpPerCapita.iloc[i])

    line.set_xdata(x_data)
    line.set_ydata(y_data)
    line.set_y1data(y1_data)
    return line,

animation = FuncAnimation(fig, func=animation_frame, interval=500)
plt.show()
```

But it returns no lines on the graph, and returns an error

```
    line.set_y1data(y1_data)
AttributeError: 'Line2D' object has no attribute 'set_y1data'
```

Any idea how to fix this? It works when I try to graph only X and Y.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have not an additional line for the GDP. Error occurs because the method `set_y1data` is not defined inside line. A possible solution looks like:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import matplotlib.animation as animation


x_data=[]
y_data=[]
y1_data=[]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(1950,2010)
ax.set_ylim(1950, 2100)



# for the purpose of illustration
xdata = np.linspace(1950, 2010, 50)
ydata = 1 * xdata
y1data = 1.01 * xdata

line_1, = ax.plot(xdata[0], ydata[0])
line_2, = ax.plot(xdata[0], y1data[0])


def animation_frame(i):
    
    line_1.set_xdata(xdata[:i])
    line_1.set_ydata(ydata[:i])
    line_2.set_xdata(xdata[:i])
    line_2.set_ydata(y1data[:i])
    return 

animation = FuncAnimation(fig, func=animation_frame, interval=500)
```